# json annotations setting null as value

Tags: java, spring-boot

Request:

```
{
"name":"iswarya",
"dept":{
    "deptName":"eee",
    "location":"firstfloor"
},
"additionalDetails":{
    "projectName":"finalyearproject"
    }
}
```

Response:

```
{

  "dept": {
  "deptName": "eee",
  "location": "firstfloor"
},
  "additionalDetails": {
  "projectName": "finalyearproject"
},
  "nickName": null
}
```

Controller:

```
@PostMapping(value = "/jsonProperty")
public Request jsonProperty(@RequestBody Request demoEntity) throws JsonProcessingException {

    System.out.println("demoEntity::" + demoEntity);

    return demoEntity;
}
```

POJO:

```
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Request {

    @JsonProperty("nickName")
    protected String name;

    protected Department dept;
    protected Details additionalDetails;

    @Data
    static class Department {
        private String deptName;
        private String location;
    }

    @Data
    static class Details {
        private String projectName;
    }

}
```

I tried with multiple JSON annotations but it's setting null only

-And also pl suggest link or any tips to know about sping-boot end to end

Comment: I found the mistake but want to know the purpose of @JsonProperty because instead of using annotation i can rename the variable to nickName ryt??

Answer (score 0):

If it is needed to deserialize field named `name`, and serialize it as `nickname`, annotation `@JsonAlias` should be used for this field:

```java
@Data
static class Request {
    @JsonAlias("name")
    private String nickname;

    private Department dept;
    private Details additionalDetails;
}
```

Then upon serialization the following result is provided:

```java
ObjectMapper om = new ObjectMapper();
        
String json = "{\r\n" + 
        "    \"name\":\"iswarya\",\r\n" + 
        "    \"dept\":{\r\n" + 
        "        \"deptName\":\"eee\",\r\n" + 
        "        \"location\":\"firstfloor\"\r\n" + 
        "    },\r\n" + 
        "    \"additionalDetails\":{\r\n" + 
        "        \"projectName\":\"finalyearproject\"\r\n" + 
        "    }\r\n" + 
        "}";
        
Request request = om.readValue(json, Request.class);
        
String str = om.writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter().writeValueAsString(request);

System.out.println(str);
```

Output

```
{
  "nickname" : "iswarya",
  "dept" : {
    "deptName" : "eee",
    "location" : "firstfloor"
  },
  "additionalDetails" : {
    "projectName" : "finalyearproject"
  }
}
```